# How to access folder & get StorageFile list in WinRT class library?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, storagefile

I am creating a class library. It contains several images. In WinRT app we can enumerate files  from specific folder like this.

```
var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync(); //which returns List<StorageFile>
```

While creating class library I can access **single** image like this

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(CLASS_NAME).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream manifestResourceStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyImage.png")
```

The below line returns all the resources of whole assembly, not for particular folder.

```
string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

I tried this one, but didn't work. It throws exception **The specified path (ms-appx:///LibraryName/Images) contains one or more invalid characters.**

```
var sf = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("ms-appx:///LibraryName/Images");
```

Now I have nearly 100+ image so in that way it will be donkey work, so how can I access the folder get the list of all the files ?

Please note I am creating class library for Windows Store App.

Answer (score 1):

I just happen to solve this.

GetFolderFromPathAsync only accepts '\' (backslash), not '/' (slash). 
When I use `Application.dataPath` from Unity Project, it reports this error too.
Now I use

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = await
StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + 
    @"\Data\Resources"
);
```

to get Unity's Resource folder.